Is curvature of the canonical line bundle always $(1,1)?$
Let $(M,g,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold with $g$ and $\omega$ denoting the Riemannian metric and the symplectic form respectively. If $J$ is a compatible almost-complex structure, then is the induced curvature of the canonical line bundle $K$ w.r.t. $J$ always $(1,1)?$ I can see it's true if it's a Kähler manifold since $K$ is holomorphic.
